# Passport JS and restify and Client sessions

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, restify

I'm stuck on an error with passport. I am building an api that is using restify. I am using client-session for session and passport with google oauth 2.

I am having trouble at the point it would serialise the user and create a session. I seem to be getting no errors however it is printing out large node objects to the console.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var massive = require('massive');
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth2').Strategy;
var _ = require('lodash');
var sessions = require("client-sessions");


var app = function(config, done) {

// declare DB and server

var server = restify.createServer(),
    db;


// Set server settings

server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath());
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(sessions({
    // cookie name dictates the key name added to the request object
    cookieName: 'Skyrail_session',
    // should be a large unguessable string
    secret: 'abc123yyighhcggfgucgdguhvgcydtfugjvhfguijkvhgcfgvcfg',
    // how long the session will stay valid in ms
    duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5
}));
server.use(passport.initialize());
server.use(passport.session());

server.use(function logger(req, res, next) {
    console.log(new Date(), req.method, req.url);
    next();
});

server.on('uncaughtException', function(request, response, route, error) {
    console.error(error.stack);
    response.send(error);
});




// passport auth settings

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: ID,
        clientSecret: SECRET,
        callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2callback',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        var isEmail = false;

        for (var i = profile.emails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (_.endsWith(profile.emails[i].value, 'test.co.uk')) {
                isEmail = true;
            }
        };

        if (isEmail) {
            // do user stuff
            done(null, profile);

        } else {

            done(null, profile);
        }

    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializing user.');

    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('deserialize user.');
    done(null, user.id);
});


// connect to the database

massive.connect({
    connectionString: config.postgres.conString
}, function(err, massiveInstance) {
    db = massiveInstance;
    done();
});


var google = passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
});


var googleCallback = passport.authenticate('google');


var authenticate = passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/fail'
})


// setup shceduler

var scheduler = require('node-schedule');


// return the appropriate method and objects.

return {

    server: server,
    db: db,
    authenticate: authenticate,
    google: google,
    googleCallback: googleCallback,
    scheduler: scheduler
}



};
   module.exports = app
```

It all works fine and I end up at google accept and then when it gets to this point.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializing user.');

    done(null, user.id);
});
```

it logs to the console and then starts throwing out node objects. I am pretty sure it has something to do with setting the cooking.

I am at a bit of loss as how to debug. There is not much information about using passport with restify.

Comment: Try removing the `id` property from your serialize and deserialize functions. Just pass the object. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/blob/master/examples/oauth2/app.js

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53574377/3076390) for an example of how to use `client-session` with Passport.

TL;DR: set `{cookieName: 'session'}` (not "Skyrail_session") and serialize the *entire* user object, not just the ID. You may need to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` if Passport doesn't do this for you.