# client-sessions module with passportjs

Tags: node.js, redirect, session-variables

My code is pasted below. In the callback method, I set the user, but when I redirect to '/' the user is no longer available. I'm using passport and client-sessions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I was initially using req.session and changed it as per this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267182/node-js-client-sessions-not-creating-req-session)

Thank you.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
if (req.session_state.user == null) {
passport.authenticate('azureoauth', { failureRedirect: './'})
}
else {
res.render('index', {user: req.session_state.user});
}
});

//This gets called by an external internet application

app.get('/auth/azureOAuth/callback', 
passport.authenticate('azureoauth', {}),
function (req, res) {
req.session_state.user = req.user;
res.redirect("/");
});
```

And in my app.js, I have the following code:

```
const clientSession = require("client-sessions");
app.use(clientSession({secret: 'blablabla', duration: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10}));
app.use(passport.initialize()); // for user authentication/authorization
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: I am not familiar with passport, but do you set your session name to be "session_state"?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-session) pretty useful, particularly this particular bit:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.session.user.email }, function(err, user) {
      if (user) {
        req.user = user;
        delete req.user.password; // delete the password from the session
        req.session.user = user;  //refresh the session value
        res.locals.user = user;
      }
      // finishing processing the middleware and run the route
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Passport expects the session cookie to be named "session". `client-sessions` can be used as a drop-in replacement for `express-session` so long as you set `{cookieName: 'session'}`. Make sure to remove `express-session` or the two will conflict.

```
const config = require('config');
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const sessions = require('client-sessions');

const app = express();

// passport expects the cookie to be named "session"
app.use(sessions({
    secret: config.get('SESSION_SECRET'), // extremely secret
    cookieName: 'session', // automatically used by passport sessions
}));

// config passport
passport.use(SomeStrategy);
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, JSON.stringify(user)));
passport.deserializeUser((userStr, done) => done(null, JSON.parse(userStr)));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```